# Calculating the Electric Potential through Computational Physics

Tags: electrostatics, computational-physics

I am working on a computational physics project which focuses on finding both the electric potential and field of certain surfaces via the relaxation method.

Things are going quite well, however I worry that the program I created is not actually performing the method.

For example:

> Consider a *7x7* metal box, whose potential is **-1** on one face and **1** on the opposite. There is no charge, so the partial differential equation (PDE) satisfies Laplace's equation.

I wrote the program (C++) in such a way that the PDE can be solved as a two dimensional problem. Here are the segments of the program which creates the array, sets the boundary conditions, and performs the relaxation method.

```
    const int N = 7; //assign value for numerical array
    
    //create arrays
    double V[N][N];//final solution
    double Vn[N][N];//inital guess
    double Vdel = 0; //difference
    
    fstream outputFile;
        
    int i,j=0;
    
    //inital values for V
    for(i=0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for( j=0;j<N;j++)
        {  
            V[i][j] = 0;          
        }
    }

    // Give boundary condition for V
    for(i=0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for( j=0;j<N;j++)
        {  
           V[i][0] = -1;
           V[i][6] = 1;
        }
    }
```

```
    // Relexation Method
    for (int iter=0;iter<10 && Vdel < 0.00001 ;iter++)
    {

        for(i=0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (j=1; j < N-1; j++)
            {
                Vn[i][j] = (V[i+1][j] + V[i-1][j] + V[i][j+1] + V[i][j-1])*0.25;//Main calculation
                Vdel += (V[i][j]-Vn[i][j]);//updates Vdel
            }

        }
        

        for (i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            for (j=1;j<N-1;j++)
            {
                V[i][j] = Vn[i][j]; //updates V
            }
        }
      }
```

The final output I get for the potential is:

```
-1, -0.508618, -0.173784, 0.0958632, 0.339737, 0.48976, 1
-1, -0.599484, -0.254206, 0.0505583, 0.335934, 0.619303, 1
-1, -0.635114, -0.294113, 0.0246417, 0.334137, 0.65152, 1
-1, -0.64686, -0.311775, 0.00798507, 0.324452, 0.652638, 1
-1, -0.640549, -0.314112, -0.00537884, 0.303049, 0.634579, 1
-1, -0.601225, -0.298744, -0.0184381, 0.258545, 0.582629, 1
-1, -0.465607, -0.261202, -0.0281748, 0.166941, 0.437392, 1
```

When in actuality it should equal to something like

```
-1, -.67, -.33, 0, .33, .67, 1
-1, -.67, -.33, 0, .33, .67, 1
-1, -.67, -.33, 0, .33, .67, 1
-1, -.67, -.33, 0, .33, .67, 1
-1, -.67, -.33, 0, .33, .67, 1
-1, -.67, -.33, 0, .33, .67, 1
-1, -.67, -.33, 0, .33, .67, 1
```

Any thoughts? It would be greatly appreciated if anyone had any advice on the topic.

P.S. (Apologies if the is the wrong forum to post this question, let me know and I can correct it immediately)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not seem to have specified  the boundary conditions  along the other two sides of the square. Without this information the solution is not unique.

Comment: That makes sense, so what you are saying that I find a way to solves that boundary  first and reapply the array into the iteration loop?

Comment: There is nothing to "solve." You can choose  any value you feel like on the side boundaries  of the square, and then  relax get a solution satisfying those boundary conditions.